# Model unavailable in sub-route

Tags: ember.js

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('products', function() {
        this.resource('product', { path: ':product_id' }, function() {
            this.route('general');
        });
    })
});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('product');
    }
});

App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('product', params.product_id);
    }
});
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product">
Showing {{ name }}
<p>{{ outlet }}</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product/general">
General template for {{ name }}
</script>
```

In the `/products/3` view the `name` shows up as it should, but not in the `/products/3/general` view. Anybody know why? 
I have tried to copy the App.ProductRoute and rename it to App.ProductGeneralRoute to find the correct model, but then the params does not exist.

Comment: Changing the route to `this.resource('product.general', { path: ':product_id/general'});` makes the model work, but the url becomes pretty funky `#/products/2/2/general`. I have tried to exclude the `product_id` parameter in the route but it seems like it's what make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ember, nested routes don't have access to their parent routes model. There are two ways to access parent models in a child route.

```
App.ProductGeneralRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('product');
  }
});
```

This sets the model on the `ProductGeneral` route by getting the model for the `ProductRoute`. Or you can use `needs`:

```
App.ProductGeneralController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['product']
});
```

In the latter example, you will have access to `controllers.product`, which will allow you to call `controllers.product.model` in the template.

See [this article](http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/01/27/controllers-needs-explained/) for more info on `needs`.

Comment: In the needs example above you probably mean `Ember.Controller.extend` - needs property is for controllers not routes.

Comment: Good catch, musta been tired :)

Comment: Hi, lets say productController needs productGeneralController. How would I make it work? it only seams to work when the controller "needing" is in higher or in the same level of route hierarchy than the requested controller